# 'None' in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a simple program above that creates a BST from a sorted array. It should parse the tree without showing the leaves which are essentially None. Could someone help explain why the program still spits out 'None'. I'm a python NooB and would appreciate any help.I have tried != 'None' along with is None but get the same results.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value
        self.nodeleft=None
        self.noderight=None

def makeBST(ia,start,end,tree):
    if (end < start):
        return None
    mid = (start + end) / 2
    n = Node(ia[mid])
    n.nodeleft = makeBST(ia, start, mid-1, tree)
    n.noderight = makeBST(ia, mid+1, end, tree)
    tree.append(n)
    return n

def printBST(root):
    print 'RR' ,root.value
    if root.nodeleft == None:
        print 'EOT'
    else:    
        print printBST(root.nodeleft)

    if root.noderight == None:
        print 'EOT'
    else:    
        print printBST(root.noderight)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    dic = []
    root = makeBST(array, 0, len(array)-1, dic)
    printBST(root)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your code was passing the return value of `printBST` to `print`. Since `printBST` does not return anything, `None` was printed.

So when you wrote:

```
print printBST(root.nodeleft)
```

that code is certain to print `None` because `printBST` does not contain a return statement and so defaults to returning `None`.

You need to change `printBST` to do this:

```
def printBST(root):
    print 'RR' ,root.value
    if root.nodeleft is None:
        print 'EOT'
    else:    
        printBST(root.nodeleft)

    if root.noderight is None:
        print 'EOT'
    else:    
        printBST(root.noderight)
```

Note also that using `is` is the correct way to test for `None`.

That said, you can make your code simpler like this:

```
def printBST(root):
    if root is None:
        print 'EOT'
        return
    print 'RR', root.value
    printBST(root.nodeleft)
    printBST(root.noderight)
```

As well as being simpler, this code has the additional benefit of not failing when presented with an empty tree.

Answer (score 2):

`printBST` should `return` the values, and not `print` them. Because it does not return anything, it defaults to `None`. That is why `printBST(root) is None`

`printBST(root)` by itself won't print the value on its own. You have to put a `print` before:

```
print printBST(root)
```

Per [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), you should never compare the NoneType singleton with equality operators (eg `==` and `!=`). Use `is None` and/or `is not None`

Comment: I did not downvote, but the answer doesn't make much sense. It looks awfully like the design of `printBST` is indeed that it should print the tree. It's not difficult to fix it to work as desired. And `printBST(root)` is indeed `None`, but then that is never printed. What is printed is `printBST(root.nodeleft)` and `printBST(root.noderight)`. You should be asking why you are getting upvotes!  ;-)